# Regex to match a subset of alpha chars

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check if a string, only one character long, is an alpha character, but not matching a special subset of them. What I'm looking for is a char that is in the range `[a-zA-Z]` but not matching any of `n, N, e, E, w, W, s, S`.

What little I currently know of regular expressions has led me to formulate the following, which doesn't work

```
[a-zA-Z][^nsewNSEW]
```

What regex do I need to achieve this?

Comment: Inside a [] you don't need the |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently trying to match a string *two* characters long. How about using a negative lookahead instead?

```
(?![nsewNSEW])[a-zA-Z]
```

A non lookahead alternative is:

```
[a-df-mo-rt-vx-zA-DF-MO-RT-VX-Z]
```

Comment: We can do better. Hold on.

Comment: I give up. Character class difference seems to be flavor-specific. +1

Comment: I mean something like `[a-zA-Z&^[newsNEWS]]`. However, I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: Java supports `[a-zA-Z&&[^newsNEWS]]`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: the non-lookahead alternative won't work. You'd need `[a-df-mo-rt-vw-zA-DF-MO-RT-VW-Z]`

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah I know I was just editing that into the question.

Answer (score 2):

If negative lookaheads aren't available, you can just use multiple ranges:

```
/[a-df-mo-rt-vx-z]/i
```

This'll match everything except the excluded characters, since we just construct multiple ranges to pass to the character class. The case-insensitive flag is used to avoid having to repeat the ranges for the capital letters.

It's worth noting that while verbose, you can construct arbitrary character classes without ranges, too:

```
/[abcdfghijklmopqrtuvxyz]/i
```

I'd use the range mechanism since it's more brief, but they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: @JanDvorak Not in all regex implementations. Ruby 1.8's regex implementation doesn't include negative lookaheads, for example. (Ruby 1.9 corrected that mistake, thankfully)

Comment: Are positive lookaheads more widely supported? Because you could use an inverted character class with one of those instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, actually. I don't have a Ruby 1.8 install handy to test with at the moment, unfortunately. But that's a good point!